# React-Bootstrap not working on IOS

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

It is difficult for me to include code samples because there is code all over my application, but I'm experiencing a general issue that I'm hoping is known.  Basically, I'm using react bootstrap.  I have code like

```
<Row><Col md={6}>blah</Col><Col md={6}>blah</Col></Row>
```

When I shrink my browser screen down, below md sizes the rows collapse correctly.  On an iPhone 6, however, they don't - there is basically no responsive functionality at all.

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I figured this one out.  I was just missing this in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: 6 years later and this was my exact problem. I'm surprised by how few people have upvoted your question and answer. In any case, this helped me a lot. Thank you.